# Get refused to connect

Tags: http, apache2

Okay, just need a little help here before I pull what hair I have left out of my head.  I've created a website (let's call it example.com).  In the URL I can put the http://192.168.1.39, http://example.com, and example.com and they all return the web page I'm expecting.  But if I put in http://www.example.com I get "This site can't be reached, refused to connect".
If you need more info, please let me know so that I can provide it, but I have set up my apache2 according to a few other websites that inform you how to set up a web server.  I'm also running Oracle VM as well.
Thank You

Comment: This is an issue related to the domain DNS settings, you have to add another  custom record (www) in the dns of your domain provider

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  However, I do have it in my DNS settings and it still didn't work.  So I install Let's Encrypt and now it works.  Don't ask me how, but now I can type http://www.example.com in the address bar and it works.  Thanks.